# Nestjs-query - How to generate the paginated and unpaginated query?

Tags: graphql, nestjs, nestjs-query

I'm using [Nestjs-query](https://doug-martin.github.io/nestjs-query/).

I have an object type (ex: `Todo`) which, most of the time, I want to use pagination to fetch the list.

```
@ObjectType('Todo')
@QueryOptions({ pagingStrategy: PagingStrategies.CURSOR })
export class Todo {
  @IDField(() => ID)
  id!: number;

  @FilterableField({ nullable: true })
  description?: string;
}
```

It generates the GraphQL query end point:

```
  todos(
    """Limit or page results."""
    paging: CursorPaging = {first: 10}

    """Specify to filter the records returned."""
    filter: TodoFilter = {}

    """Specify to sort results."""
    sorting: [TodoSort!] = []
  ): TodoConnection!
```

But on some occasions, I want to fetch the entire list (unpaginated) of TODOs. But `paging.first` cannot be `null` or smaller than `1`.

Is there a way to fetch the unpaginated list without writing a new query endpoint by hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible by adding a new resolver to the module:

```
NestjsQueryGraphQLModule.forFeature({
  imports: [TodoModule],
  resolvers: [
    {
      // Assuming Todo is decorated with `@QueryOptions({ pagingStrategy: PagingStrategies.CURSOR })`
      DTOClass: Todo,
      EntityClass: Todo,
      // ...
    },
    {
      DTOClass: Todo,
      EntityClass: Todo,
      pagingStrategy: PagingStrategies.NONE,
      read: {
        // Give a custom name to not conflict with the first resolver.
        many: { name: 'todoUnpaginated' },
      },
      // ...
    },
  ],
}),
```

And it generates the schema:

```
  todos(
    """Limit or page results."""
    paging: CursorPaging = {first: 10}

    """Specify to filter the records returned."""
    filter: TodoFilter = {}

    """Specify to sort results."""
    sorting: [TodoSort!] = []
  ): TodoConnection!
  todosUnpaginated(
    """Specify to filter the records returned."""
    filter: TodoFilter = {}

    """Specify to sort results."""
    sorting: [TodoSort!] = []
  ): [Todo!]!
```